# Middleware for custom request

Tags: php, laravel

I created my request in which I validate the data. Some of this data I need to convert to JSON. 
For this, I decided to create middleware. But when I try to get a request in the controller, it doesn't have anything I added in the middleware.
This seems to be because it is not my own request 'MyRequest $request' that gets into the middleware. How can this be resolved?

middlevare

```
class TransformData
{

    /**
     * @param $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
     $next($request);

        $request->merge(['user_id' => \Auth::user()->id]);
     $request->merge(['select_products' => json_encode($request->select_products)]);
        return $request;
    }
}
```

my request is called OfferRequest, there are just validation rules

controller

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('transform.offer.data')->only('store');
    }

}
```

```
    public function store(OfferRequest $request)
    {


        $all = $request->all();
        dd($all); // there is nothing here that I added in the middleware

    }
```

I added the middleware to the kernel - protected $routeMiddleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Middleware like the following :

**TransformData.php**

```
class TransformData
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $request->merge([
            'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id,
            'select_products' => json_encode($request->select_products)
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The above would work, but I would suggest you to use `prepareForValidation()` method [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.html#method_prepareForValidation) in form request class for update request data.

Using `prepareForValidation()` method you could add or update your request parameters.
**OfferRequest.php**

```
class AccountFilterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        //your rules
    }

    /**
    * Modify the input.
    */
    public function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id,
            'select_products' => json_encode($request->select_products)
        ]);
    }
}
```

`prepareForValidation()` method is executed before validation so you can add new data or update data and validate those.